# How to make a jumping in python?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm doing own game with the help Python. I need to make a jumping to my sprite can jump. However, my sprite can't jump. If my program had 1 and more mistakes, my game wouldn't able to work. Please, find mistake to my sprite can jump. Here's my program:

```py
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import os
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60
usr_y = 400

# Задаем цвета
GREEN = (75, 0, 130)
BLUE = (255, 20, 147)

# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Mini-games by Latypov Vildan 10'a' Class")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH - 360
        self.rect.centery = HEIGHT - 200

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        


    

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)


def print_text(message, x, y, font_color = (0, 0, 0), font_type = 'фыы.ttf', font_size = 30):
    font_type = pygame.font.Font(font_type, font_size)
    text = font_type.render(message, True, font_color)
    screen.blit(text, (x, y))

print_text('Hi', 250, 250)

jump = False
counter = -30

def make():
    global  usr_y, counter, jump
    if counter >=  -30:
        usr_y-= counter / 2.5
        counter -= 1
    else:
        counter = 30
        jump = False
    

# Цикл игры

running = True
while running:
    # Держим цикл на правильной скорости
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Ввод процесса (события)
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:    
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.key == K_SPACE:
                jump = True

                if jump:
                    make()
                
                


                                       
    # Обновление
    all_sprites.update()
    # Рендеринг
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # После отрисовки всего, переворачиваем экран
    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to do the jump in the application loop. The state `jump` is set once when the event occurs. However, the jumping needs to be animated in consecutive frames.

Your event loop is mixed up and you must change the coordinate of the player  object instead of `usr_y`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH - 360
        self.rect.centery = HEIGHT - 200
        self.y = self.rect.y                # <--- floating point y coordinate

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y = round(self.y)         # <--- update player rectangle
        self.speedx = 0
        # [...]
```

```py
jump = False
counter = 30

def make():
    global counter, jump
    if counter >= -30:
        player.y -= counter / 2.5  # <--- change player.y
        counter -= 1
    else:
        counter = 30
        jump = False
```

```py
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False 
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:    
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.key == K_SPACE:
                jump = True

    # INDENTATION
    #<----------|
    if jump:
        make()

    # [...]
```

[image]

Comment: @ВильданЛатыпов I've extended the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I watched videos about how to make a game. I have tried solve the problem of jumping for 15 days, but you helped me. You're my savior!!!

Comment: @ВильданЛатыпов Thank you. You're welcome.